# Multiple Reduced Mana gems

Tags: path-of-exile

If I put two lvl1 Reduced Mana gems into same linked sockets does it mean the linked skill gets 90%+90% cost multiplier?

My build is CI and I can run max 2 auras. I was thinking if there was a way so I could run 3-4 auras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support gems cannot stack with eachother, you cannot have 2 support gems that are the same affecting the 1 skill.

There are other ways to allow you to use more than 2 auras though (there are heaps of -manareserved nodes on the passive skill tree)

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Path of Exile wiki page on Support Gems](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Support),

> However, if two copies of a support gem are linked to the same skill, only the higher level gem will be used.

So, no. Only the stronger of the two Reduced Mana gems will take effect.